# Dimension 2 in both shapes must be equal, but are 3 and 1

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, keras-layer

I am getting a value error while trying to make a GAN work on RGB photos in Tensorflow.

in the video that I'm following it works in black and white(59:50): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LZov6445YAY&list=WL&index=4&t=3426s&ab_channel=SundogEducationwithFrankKane

I am trying to make it work with RGB color channels instead of black and white. But i get the error above.

I have changed:

```
tensor = tf.io.decode_image(dataset, channels=1, dtype=tf.dtypes.float32)
```

to:

```
tensor = tf.io.decode_image(dataset, channels=3, dtype=tf.dtypes.float32)
```

---

```
tensor = tf.io.decode_image(img, channels=1, dtype=tf.dtypes.float32)
```

to:

```
tensor = tf.io.decode_image(img, channels=3, dtype=tf.dtypes.float32)
```

---

```
dataset = np.reshape(dataset, (-1, 28, 28, 1))
```

to:

```
dataset = np.reshape(dataset, (-1, 28, 28, 3))
```

---

```
keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(28, 28, 1)),
```

to:

```
keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(28, 28, 3)),
```

Full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\m8\Desktop\idek1.py", line 153, in <module>
    dLoss = trainDStep(batch)
  File "C:\Users\m8\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\traceback_utils.py", line 153, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "C:\Users\m8\AppData\Local\Temp\__autograph_generated_filegoihnx0n.py", line 15, in tf__trainDStep
    x = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(tf).concat, ([ag__.ld(data), ag__.ld(fake)],), dict(axis=0), fscope)
ValueError: in user code:

    File "C:\Users\m8\Desktop\idek1.py", line 94, in trainDStep  *
        x = tf.concat([data, fake], axis=0)

    ValueError: Dimension 2 in both shapes must be equal, but are 3 and 1. Shapes are [28,28,3] and [28,28,1]. for '{{node concat_1}} = ConcatV2[N=2, T=DT_FLOAT, Tidx=DT_INT32](data, sequential/conv2d_transpose_2/Sigmoid, concat_1/axis)' with input shapes: [16,28,28,3], [16,28,28,1], [] and with computed input tensors: input[2] = <0>.
```

Full code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os
import pathlib
import numpy as np

tf.random.set_seed(1)

print(len(tf.config.list_physical_devices("GPU")))

config = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
session = tf.compat.v1.Session(config=config)

data_dir = "C:/Users/m8/Desktop/test_fro_tensorflow/train/training/"

dataset = tf.io.read_file("C:/Users/m8/Desktop/test_fro_tensorflow/val/validation/img (1).jpg")
tensor = tf.io.decode_image(dataset, channels=3, dtype=tf.dtypes.float32)
tensor = tf.image.resize(tensor, [28, 28])
dataset = tf.expand_dims(tensor, axis=0)

for file in os.listdir(data_dir):
    f = os.path.join(data_dir, file)
    full_path = data_dir + file
    img = tf.io.read_file(full_path)
    tensor = tf.io.decode_image(img, channels=3, dtype=tf.dtypes.float32)
    tensor = tf.image.resize(tensor, [28, 28])
    new_tensor = tf.expand_dims(tensor, axis=0)
    dataset = np.concatenate([dataset, new_tensor])

print(dataset.shape)

dataset = np.expand_dims(dataset, -1).astype("float32") / 255

BATCH_SIZE = 16

dataset = np.reshape(dataset, (-1, 28, 28, 3))
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(dataset)
dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=1024).batch(BATCH_SIZE)

from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

NOISE_DIM = 150


generator = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(NOISE_DIM,)),
    layers.Dense(7*7*256),
    layers.Reshape(target_shape=(7, 7, 256)),
    layers.Conv2DTranspose(256, 3, activation="LeakyReLU", strides=2, padding="same"),
    layers.Conv2DTranspose(128, 3, activation="LeakyReLU", strides=2, padding="same"),
    layers.Conv2DTranspose(1, 3, activation="sigmoid", padding="same"),
])

generator.summary()

discriminator = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(28, 28, 3)),
    layers.Conv2D(256, 3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="same"),
    layers.Conv2D(128, 3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="same"),
    layers.Dense(64, activation="relu"),
    layers.Flatten(),
    layers.Dropout(0.2),
    layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")
])

discriminator.summary()

optimizerG = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001, beta_1=0.5)
optimizerD = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.003, beta_1=0.5)

lossFn = keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True)

gAccMetric = tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy()
dAccMetric = tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy()

@tf.function
def trainDStep(data):
    batchSize = tf.shape(data)[0]

    noise = tf.random.normal(shape=(batchSize, NOISE_DIM))
    y_true = tf.concat(
        [
            tf.ones(batchSize, 1),

            tf.zeros(batchSize, 1)
        ],
        axis=0
    )

    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        fake = generator(noise)
        x = tf.concat([data, fake], axis=0)
        y_pred = discriminator(x)
        discriminatorLoss = lossFn(y_true, y_pred)

    grads = tape.gradient(discriminatorLoss, discriminator.trainable_weights)
    optimizerD.apply_gradients(zip(grads, discriminator.trainable_weights))

    dAccMetric.update_state(y_true, y_pred)

    return {
        "discriminator_loss": discriminatorLoss,
        "discriminator_accuracy": dAccMetric.result()
    }

@tf.function
def trainGStep(data):
    batchSize = tf.shape(data)[0]
    noise = tf.random.normal(shape=(batchSize, NOISE_DIM))
    y_true = tf.ones(batchSize, 1)

    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        y_pred = discriminator(generator(noise))
        generatorLoss = lossFn(y_true, y_pred)

    grads = tape.gradient(generatorLoss, generator.trainable_weights)
    optimizerG.apply_gradients(zip(grads, generator.trainable_weights))

    gAccMetric.update_state(y_true, y_pred)

    return {
        "generator_loss": generatorLoss,
        "generator_accuracy": gAccMetric.result()
    }

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def plotImages(model):
    images = model(np.random.normal(size=(4, NOISE_DIM)))

    plt.figure(figsize=(9, 9))

    for i, image in enumerate(images):
        plt.subplot(2,2,i+1)
        plt.imshow(np.squeeze(image, -1), cmap="Greys_r")
        plt.axis("off")

    plt.show();

for epoch in range(50):

    dLossSum = 0
    gLossSum = 0
    dAccSum = 0
    gAccSum = 0
    cnt = 0


    for batch in dataset:

        dLoss = trainDStep(batch)
        dLossSum += dLoss["discriminator_loss"]
        dAccSum += dLoss["discriminator_accuracy"]

        gLoss = trainGStep(batch)
        gLossSum += dLoss["discriminator_loss"]
        gAccSum += dLoss["discriminator_accuracy"]


        cnt += 1


    print("E:{}, Loss G:{:0.4f}, Loss D:{:0.4f}, Acc G:%{:0.2f}, Acc D:%{:0.2f}".format(
        epoch,
        gLossSum/cnt,
        dLossSum/cnt,
        100 * gAccSum/cnt,
        100 * dAccSum/cnt
    ))

    if epoch % 2 == 0:
        plotImages(generator)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us start by inspecting your error alongside the code you have provided.

```
        x = tf.concat([data, fake], axis=0)

    ValueError: Dimension 2 in both shapes must be equal, but are 3 and 1. Shapes are [28,28,3] and [28,28,1]. for '{{node concat_1}} = ConcatV2[N=2, T=DT_FLOAT, Tidx=DT_INT32](data, sequential/conv2d_transpose_2/Sigmoid, concat_1/axis)' with input shapes: [16,28,28,3], [16,28,28,1], [] and with computed input tensors: input[2] = <0>.
```

The main takeaway from this error is that `data` and `fake` cannot be concatenated - the reason being that they don't match size-wise. As the error states,

- `data` has the shape `[28,28,3]` (which is expected as you have made the changes to have RGB inputs
- `fake` has the shape `[28,28,1]` which is not the same as the shape of `data`

Our solution is to somehow fix the `fake` variable's shape to match that of `data`.

---

We see that `fake` is created in the code in the line

```
fake = generator(noise)
```

And `generator` is defined as

```py
generator = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(NOISE_DIM,)),
    ...
    ...
    layers.Conv2DTranspose(1, 3, activation="sigmoid", padding="same"),
])
```

The last layer of the `generator` seems to be a `Conv2DTranspose` but it is using just `1` output channel (the first argument). Here is our error!

To fix it, it would just require the change of making it output 3 channel rather than 1 as

```
    layers.Conv2DTranspose(3, 3, activation="sigmoid", padding="same"),
```

Comment: @S P Sharan Thank you so much! Fixed the error, also as a newbie the detailed explanation really helped as well.

Comment: @somethingidk glad to know it helped you. Please upvote and mark this as the accepted answer (green tick).